# How do i render data from db into dashboard page generated by ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is it possible to render data from other db files or with query to show in the default dashboard page generated by `ActiveAdmin` in Ruby on Rails. I am very new to the engine and would like an explanation on how to do it?

So far when i try to call the db by it's name, table_for cannot render any data, which i suppose is the correct response:

```
# columns do
    #   panel "Test" do
    #     table_for Test do
    #       column "Title", :name
    #       column "Id", :id
    #     end
    #   end
    # end
```

The file where i am trying to load data:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should be able to render a table based on an ActiveRecord query result. Instead of using the class name `table_for Test do`, you should use the ActiveRecord query `table_for Test.all do` or your query. For example:

```rb
panel "Pending Dealers" do
  table_for Dealer.pending.last(5) do
    column :id
    column :name do |dealer|
      link_to dealer.name, admin_dealer_path(dealer)
    end
    column :email
    column :created_at
  end
end
```

You can display any information using the [Arbre Components](https://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html) o rendering an ERB file partial with `render partial: 'important_information'`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use `panel`, `table_for Order.all`, etc. Here's an example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
  content do
    columns do
      column span: 2 do
        panel "Processing Orders" do
          h5 do
            Order.processing.count
          end
        end
      end
      column span: 2 do
        panel "Completed Orders" do
          h5 do
            Order.completed.count
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```